# Unable to Parse XML in Shell

Tags: xml, shell, xpath, xmllint

SO, below is my xml I am trying to parse. First I used XmlSlurper in my Jnekinsfile, parsing was easy but I faced performace issues in pipeline.
Now I am using XMLlint, but it isnt as easy as XmlSlurper :(

```xml
<metadata modelVersion="1.1.0">
  <groupId>com.test.test.test</groupId>
  <artifactId>myApp-ear</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.0-10-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <versioning>
    <snapshot>
      <timestamp>20200803.052228</timestamp>
      <buildNumber>3</buildNumber>
    </snapshot>
    <lastUpdated>20200803052228</lastUpdated>
    <snapshotVersions>
      <snapshotVersion>
        <extension>ear</extension>
        <value>4.0.0-10-20200803.052228-3</value>
        <updated>20200803052228</updated>
      </snapshotVersion>
      <snapshotVersion>
        <extension>pom</extension>
        <value>4.0.0-10-20200803.052228-3</value>
        <updated>20200803052228</updated>
      </snapshotVersion>
    </snapshotVersions>
  </versioning>
</metadata>
```

I want to parse and fetch value of `<value>4.0.0-10-20200803.052228-3</value>` from `<snapshotVersion> with <extension>` type **ear**.

**This is my code snippet,**

```shell
 $(xmllint --xpath "/metadata/artifactId/text()"
 metadataFile)-$(xmllint --xpath
 "/metadata/versioning/snapshotVersions[0]/value/text()"
 metadataFile).$(xmllint --xpath
 "/metadata/versioning/snapshotVersions[0]/extension/text()"
 metadataFile)
```

**Output:**

> ++ xmllint --xpath '/metadata/artifactId/text()' metadataFile
> ++ xmllint --xpath '/metadata/versioning/snapshotVersions[0]/value/text()' metadataFile
> XPath set is empty
> ++ xmllint --xpath '/metadata/versioning/snapshotVersions[0]/extension/text()'
> metadataFile XPath set is empty

Kindly help.

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: Doesn't `//snapshotVersion[extension="ear"]/value/text()` work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faced with an error like that, I usually start trying to shorten my xpath expression until I find out where I'm getting unexpected data. Your complete expressions is:

```
/metadata/versioning/snapshotVersions[0]/value/text()
```

That's returning an empty set. If we try instead:

```
/metadata/versioning/snapshotVersions
```

We see this returns:

```
<snapshotVersions>
      <snapshotVersion>
        <extension>ear</extension>
        <value>4.0.0-10-20200803.052228-3</value>
        <updated>20200803052228</updated>
      </snapshotVersion>
      <snapshotVersion>
        <extension>pom</extension>
        <value>4.0.0-10-20200803.052228-3</value>
        <updated>20200803052228</updated>
      </snapshotVersion>
    </snapshotVersions>
```

Great! But if we add `[0]` to that, we get the empty set again:

```
$ xmllint --xpath '/metadata/versioning/snapshotVersions[0]' metadata.xml
XPath set is empty
```

There are two reasons for that:

1. You need to apply the `[n]` operator to the elements that make up the list (so, `snapshotVersion`, not `snapshotVersions`), and
2. Xpath starts enumerating elements from `1` rather than `0`.

So this seems to do what you want:

```
$ xmllint --xpath '/metadata/versioning/snapshotVersions/snapshotVersion[1]/value/text()' metadata.xml
4.0.0-10-20200803.052228-3
```

Comment: this worked! Thanks much for the solution and good insights on xmllint @larsks.